# Finding Uppercase Character then Adding Space

Tags: sql, uppercase

I bought a SQL World City/State database. In the state database it has the state names pushed together. Example: "NorthCarolina", or "SouthCarolina"...

IS there a way in SQL to loop and find the uppercase characters and add a space???

this way "NorthCarolina" becomes "North Carolina"???

Answer (score 7):

Create this function

```
if object_id('dbo.SpaceBeforeCaps') is not null
    drop function dbo.SpaceBeforeCaps
GO
create function dbo.SpaceBeforeCaps(@s varchar(100)) returns varchar(100)
as
begin
    declare @return varchar(100);
    set @return = left(@s,1);
    declare @i int;
    set @i = 2;
    while @i <= len(@s)
    begin
        if ASCII(substring(@s,@i,1)) between ASCII('A') and ASCII('Z')
            set @return = @return + ' ' + substring(@s,@i,1)
        else
            set @return = @return + substring(@s,@i,1)
        set @i = @i + 1;
    end;
    return @return;
end;
GO
```

Then you can use it to update your database

```
update tbl set statename = select dbo.SpaceBeforeCaps(statename);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to approach this

1. Construct a function using a pattern and the [`PATINDEX` feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx).
2. Chain minimal [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) statements for each case (e.g. `REPLACE(state_name, 'hC', 'h C' for your example case)`.  This seems is kind of a hack, but might actually give you the best performance, since you have such a small set of replacements.

Comment: Like how you call PATINDEX feature

Comment: I previously tried PATINDEX. Could not get it to work with finding uppercase. WORLD States.... so it's A LOT of data.

Comment: @cha - it is a language feature.  what would you call it?

Comment: Did not want to offence you. Just sometimes at our team we call bugs "undocumented features" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undocumented_feature

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely **cannot** create functions and need this as a one-off, you can use a recursive CTE to break the string up (and add the space at the same time where required), then recombine the characters using FOR XML.  Elaborate example below:

```
-- some sample data
create table #tmp (id int identity primary key, statename varchar(100));
insert #tmp select 'NorthCarolina';
insert #tmp select 'SouthCarolina';
insert #tmp select 'NewSouthWales';

-- the complex query updating the "statename" column in the "#tmp" table
;with cte(id,seq,char,rest) as (
    select id,1,cast(left(statename,1) as varchar(2)), stuff(statename,1,1,'')
      from #tmp
     union all
    select id,seq+1,case when ascii(left(rest,1)) between ascii('A') and ascii('Z')
                         then ' ' else '' end + left(rest,1)
         , stuff(rest,1,1,'')
      from cte
     where rest > ''
), recombined as (
  select a.id, (select b.char+''
                  from cte b
                 where a.id = b.id
              order by b.seq
                   for xml path, type).value('/','varchar(100)') fixed
    from cte a
group by a.id
)
update t
   set statename = c.fixed
  from #tmp t
  join recombined c on c.id = t.id
 where statename != c.fixed;

-- check the result
select * from #tmp

----------- -----------
id          statename
----------- -----------
1           North Carolina
2           South Carolina
3           New South Wales
```